# Persisting Web Requests in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net

I would like to build some kind of JSON.API scheduler service to play web request later on my production server.

It should be possible to POST this to localhost/app/events on my development machine:

```
{
    “schedule”: { 
            “start”:”2014-12-31”, 
             “repeat”:”annualy” 
     },
    “requst”: {
           “verb”:”POST” ,
           “href”:“http://localhost/app/emails”,
            “body”:{
                 “type”:”HappyNewYearWishes”
             }
     }
}
```

Given ASP.NET API as an implementation mechanism, how to parse and persist “request” part to database, so Production Server will be able to

```
POST /emails
{
       “type”:”HappyNewYearWishes”
}
```

according to the schedule? The problem is that the deployment root is different for development machine and production server, so I cannot persist “href” as it is. What kind of mechanisms of ASP.NET Web API for route parsing, transformation, and persistence are useful here?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the *Route* parameters using

```
RouteData.Values
```

Also you can get the eventual querystring parameters using

```
Request.Url.Query
```

With the results of these two objects stored, you can easily rebuild the URL.

Comment: Given JSON "request" object, how can I get RouteData? How can I build a request from it? Could you please show some example?